# Enabling Exchange Online SMTP Client Authentication with Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, exchange-server, smtpclient

I'm trying to enable Authenticated SMTP in Exchange Online via PowerShell.
I was semi successful with my attempts.

`$Users = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize unlimited`
`$Users | where {$_.SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled -eq $true} | Set-CASMailbox -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $False`

This resulted in about 75% of the users having SMTP Authentication activated. But weirdly not all of them.

`$Users = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize unlimited`
`$Users | where {$_.SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled -eq $true -or $null -or ""} | Set-CASMailbox -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $False`

Showed the same results.
As did:

`$Users = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize unlimited`
`$Users | where {$_.ImapEnabled -eq $true} | Set-CASMailbox -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $False`

So apparently this has nothing to do with the state of `SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled` since I tried all possible states and used `ImapEnabled -eq $true` as a condition which is `$true` for every user.

I just started working with PowerShell and only have some basic programming knowledge. This setting has to be changed for about 80 accounts right now, but in a week or two about 4000 accounts will be synchronized with AzureAD and therefore Exchange Online. So far I haven't received an answer from the company which synchronizes the accounts on wether or not it's possible to set the state of  `SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled` when the synchronization happens. I expect that I will have to do it myself.

All users have an active Office 365 Licence and an active Exchange Online Plan.

Does anyone have some insight as to why only most but no all of the users accept this setting?

Edit:
When trying to execute your suggested script or when trying to execute my own commands I run into the issue that '$user' returns '$null' which I don't understand.

```
Setting SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled for  failed, error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
```

This also happens when im only executing this:

```
$Users = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach($user in $users) {Write-Host "$($user.DisplayName)"}
```

It just returns nothing.
I think there is something fundamental that I don't understand.
If I just list the contents of '$users' PowerShell returns a list of all the users with the related settings like 'SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your complete organization to use the same setting, you should leave the values of the users $null. Instead set the TransportConfig.

```
Get-TransportConfig
```

Then check the value. If it is set to 'False', all users with a $null-value for SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled will have the default setting of 'False'.

If set to 'True', change to 'False' instead:

```
Set-TransportConfig -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false
```

To answer your original question, of why the users are not updated properly. I think it has something to do with the fact that 'SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled' is not a filterable attribute in the first place. So you will always have to query your complete dataset, which is not very elegant.

You could do something like the following to check and see what happens exactly:

```
$Users = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach($user in $Users){
    if($user.SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled -eq $null -or $user.SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled -eq $true){
        try{
            Set-CASMailbox -Identity $user.ExchangeObjectId.guid -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "$($user.DisplayName) succesfully set to correct state" -ForegroundColor Green
        }catch{
            Write-Host "Setting SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled for $($user.DisplayName) failed, error: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }else{
        Write-Host "$($user.DisplayName) already has the correct state: $($user.SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled)" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

But personally I would change the above script to use it to set all values to $null:

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity $user.ExchangeObjectId.guid -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $null -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, i will try to set the values to $null.

But based on this link:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-smtp-authentication-failing-even-with/4e2dcfc4-2626-4c3b-a945-9ff1b3404539?page=2
(Timme B81s answer on June 26th - page 2)

I was under the assumption that it is required to set the global value to $false and also the the per user value to $false. I was aware that there is a global setting for this but since it did not work even when no changes were made I took the information from the post above and tried to set it for all users.